# Image Warping. From one image to another

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing

I'm using the word "warping" because this is the word that explain the most what I want to do, but I'm not sure this is the suitable term...

What I want to achieve is to find the operation that will modify an image into another image.

I'll explain myself : I have two images that are almost similar (the same scene, the same moment but not the same point of view), but I want to know how to transform Image1 into Image2, basically all the transformations I have to do. To do so, I was thinking about :

If I want to transform `I1` into `I2` :

1. Convert I1 and I2 into B&W pictures.
2. Apply Sobel filter.
3. Create patches with both images (Little image that are part of big images). Something like 15px*15px patches.
4. Find differences between I1.patch(x,y) and I2.patch(x,y)  and find the transformation to transform I1.patch(x,y) into I2.patch(x,y).
5. For all patches, apply the transformation on the coloured image.

Do you think it's a good idea to do it like that? Do anyone know another method that could be better?

And if you think it's a good idea, have you an idea for point number 4 above? Because I have an idea, but I think I'm a little naive to think it'll work: Use the two Matrices and find the path to transform one into another with the least possible operations or use a standard warping algorithm.

I'm will use OpenCV3.0 on windows 7 computer.

Thanks for reading, and I hope this is understandable.

Have a nice evening! :)

Comment: Do you mean *morphing*, rather than warping? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphing

Comment: I don't think just working with individual patches could would get a good result because if an object has moved from the area of one patch to another it wouldn't be picked up at all. Might as well do a crossfade at that point...

Comment: robinson: I already checked the morphing solution. But i'm pretty sure warping is more suitable here. But i'll continue to check since I am totally sure.
@MattiVirkkunen That's true. I was thinking about positionning the 2 pictures the better so I had less errors but even with that, that's a problem I have to solve... 
What are you thinking about doing a crossfade? To apply a crossfade to my image?

Comment: What I meant is that unless you look for similarities beyond the equivalent patches in both images you might as well do a simple crossfade, which isn't what you want.

Comment: Maybe if I do all patches possible and find the ones that have the best rank in term of validity? So maybe the first patch will be (15x15) from pixel (0,0) and the second one will be (15x15) from pixel (3,3) (so all the modifications will be done).
Or try to create several patch size (1 pass with patch 15x15, then 1 pass with patch 30x30)?
If i consider first method, since images are 2048x2048 i'll have something like 4M operations, maybe it is too much ahah

Comment: Do you think this is possible using optical flow?

Comment: Are You trying to match calibrated stereo images, or they could have an angle between them (image rotated)?

Comment: It's more a problem of projection :) One is orthographic, other is perspective :)

Comment: Out of interest, did you have any luck with this problem?